# jQuery post size limitation using canvas.todataurl()

Tags: php, jquery, canvas

I'm trying to upload a canvas.todataurl() image (getUserMedia)  to server using jQuery post and php to handle the data, but I'm having some problems. All the images I'm uploading end up being corrupted, half of the image is missing. I also have a MySQL database where I'm storing data related to the image (title, text, date and the like). It seems that the more I have the related data the more the image get corrupted.

Therefore, I'm wondering is this a browser limitation or does this have something to do with jQuery post. I've also checked the PHP max_post_size and it's 16mb, so that shouldn't be a problem. I don't have access to the server settings. I'm quite puzzled with this, what can I do? Is it possible to divide the canvas.todataurl() to multiple parts and then post?

JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var video = document.getElementById('videoStream');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasImage');
var status = document.getElementById('status');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
//var others = document.getElementById('others');
var imageHolder;
document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'none';
var image = null; //  kuvan datauri joka lähtee php:lle

window.URL || (window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL); 
navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

// toString : function() {return "video,audio";} canarya varten
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false, toString : function() {return "video,audio";}}, onSuccess, onError);
} else {
    status.innerText = "getUserMedia is not supported in your browser, sorry :(";
}

function onSuccess(stream) {

    var source;
    if (window.webkitURL) {
        source = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
        source = stream; // Opera ja Firefox
    }

    video.width = 500;
    video.height = 375;
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.src = source;

}

function onError() {

    status.innerText = "Please allow access to your webcam.";

}

button.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {

    // Poistetaan aikaisempi kuva jos sellaista on
    //document.body.removeChild(imageHolder);

    // luodaan kuva uudestaan
    imageHolder = document.createElement('figure');
    imageHolder.id = 'imageHolder';
    document.body.appendChild(imageHolder);
    img = document.createElement('img');
    imageHolder.appendChild(img); 

    // kuva on yhtäsuuri kuin video
    canvas.width = video.width;
    canvas.height = video.height;
    img.width = 350;
    img.height = 225;

    // piirretään canvasille kuva videosta
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}, false);

button.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {      
    // Canvasilta kuvaksi levylle tallentamista varten
    canvas.style.display = 'none';
    video.style.display = 'none';
    button.style.display = 'none';
    others.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'block';
    image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    img.src = image;
}, false);

// jquery post
$('#send').click(function(){
    var image2 = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    $.post('upload.php',
    {
            title: $('#title').val(),
            blog: $('#blog').val(),
            category: $('#category').val(),
            author: $('#author').val(),
            imagename: image2
    });
});


}, false);
```

PHP upload.php

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
$img = $_POST['imagename'];
$img = str_replace(' ','+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png'; 
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Tiedoston tallennus ei sitten onnistu millään...';
$imagename = $file; // this is the file name for the MySQL database
```

My problem is (I think) image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); and the jQuery post. 
The canvas.toDataUrl() string is about 700 000 letters long.

Comment: How long is the resulting canvas.toDataURL string that you're dealing with? I've read about people having problem decoding large base64 strings.

Comment: It can vary depending on the image taken with getUserMedia, but I'd say about 700 000 letters.

Comment: Having the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221750/html2canvas-400kb-max-size-cutting-off-image-at-same-byte-for-most

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this:

```
<?php 
$decoded = ""; 
for ($i=0; $i < ceil(strlen($encoded)/256); $i++) 
   $decoded = $decoded . base64_decode(substr($encoded,$i*256,256)); 
?>
```

I got it from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#92980

The code basically tries to *partially* decodes the base64 string. I haven't tested this though. I've never dealt with base64 images as big as what you're working with.

Comment: I already tried that, didn't make any difference, still half of the image missing. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Split it, use two, variables and merge in php, works fine. ;-)

```
var resourcelength_all = resource.length;
var resourcelength_split = resourcelength_all / 2;
var resource_part1 = resource.substr(0, resourcelength_split);
var resource_part2 = resource.substr(resourcelength_split, resourcelength_all);
```